# Best way to traverse millions of CSV records

Tags: node.js, json, csv

I have a CSV with over 20 millions data records and I would like to manipulate this data by fetching and returning data based on time and token fields. My initial approach was to convert the CSV data to a json and traverse through it but that takes too much time. What is the best and fastest way to do this? Your help will truly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making chunks of data, like getting 100 records and then manipulating it.

You can use a `for loop` for the same like :

```
for (let i = 0; i <= csvDataCount; i += 100) {
  //Your manipulation here
}
```

or more better you can do this:

It will create chunks of data of what size you want

```
function createChunks(array = [], chunkSize) {
  if (!chunkSize) { return array }

  const _array = [...array]
  let chunks = []
  do {
    chunks.push(_array.splice(0, chunkSize))
  } while (_array.length)
  return chunks
}
```

Later you can use loop to manipulate the data

```
  // Process in Chunks for Large Dataset
  const dataChunks = createChunks(csvDataArray, 100)
  for (const item of dataChunks) {
    //do the manipulation here
  }
```